# What does path-connectedness of $I$ have to do with this at all?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am utterly confused.

> Q. Show that $X=\{0,1\}$ with the discrete toplogy is not contractible.

Well i need to show that $X$ isn't homotopy equivalent to $\{0\}$.

My argument is this

> We need continuous maps $f:X \to \{0\}$ and $g:\{0\} \to X$. we can deal with $f$ just being the constant map but for $g$, it needs to be $g^{-1}(1)$ and $g^{-1}(0)$ to be open in $\{0\}$. But then this requires $g^{-1}(1)=g^{-1}(0)=0 \in \{0\}$. Given that $\{0\}$ is only one-point, $g(0)$ must be mapped to some single $x \in X$ so we cannot have this and thus no continuous $g$ exists from $\{0\} \to X$. Hence $X$ is not homotopy equivalent to $\{0\}$.

However, the solution is bizarre to me because it switches arguments to $I$ being path-connected or something. **What does $I$ being path-connected have anything to do with homotopy equivalence here??**

> (It's the same up to "requires $g^{-1}(1)=g^{-1}(0)=0 \in \{0\}$" in mine).As $I$ is path connected there is no path $\omega:I \to X$ such that $\omega(0)=0$ and $\omega(1)=1$. Thus $X$ is not path-connected so not contractible.

So not path-connected=not contractible? First off, I never learned that in class. Nor in my lecture notes.

Second and most importantly, I really don't understand

> > As $I$ is path connected there is no path $\omega:I \to X$ such that $\omega(0)=0$ and $\omega(1)=1$.

I can "kind of imagine" that there isn't a path from $0,1$ in $X$ because well i'ts discrete thereby not continuous(and paths are defined to be continuous). But **why does $I$ being path connected** come into play at all in this argument/ What relation does it have with $X$'s path-connectedness?

Comment: If you can only *imagine* that there is no path $w:[0,1]\to\{0,1\}$ from $0$ to $1$ but not proving it, I suggest you stop looking at the question and think about this instead.

Comment: Moreover, you «what elation does it have with $X$'s path-connectedness?» is very weird. The very definittion of of path-connectedness is that there be a path from $0$ to $1$ in $X$!

Comment: The error in your first argument is assuming that $g$ is onto. For example $g(0)=0$ is continuous and $g^{-1}(1)=\emptyset $ is open.

Comment: Well, I say imagine because, $X$ contains $0,1$ only, and well, there's not way for this to be continuous with $t \in I$ for any function $\omega(t)$...can it? It's just intuition, which I'm not entirely proud or happy, it's rather me trying my best to convince myself since I cannot come up with a rigorous proof by myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A space $X$ being contractible is the same as saying that the identity $1_X$ is homotopic to a constant map.

Let $X$ be contractible, denote by
$$H:I\times X\longrightarrow X$$
be the homotopy from $1_X$ to a constant map with image $x_0$. Let $x\in X$ be any point, then the map
$$\gamma(t) := H(t,x)$$
is a continuous path from $x$ to $x_0$. Therefore, any contractible space is path connected.

It follows that showing that a space is not path connected is enough to prove that it is not contractible.

---

For the second question, in fact you only need the fact that $I$ is connected, without caring about its path connectedness. As the image of a connected space by a continuous map is again connected, you have that any map from $I$ to a discrete space must be constant. This implies that there is no path linking $0$ to $1$ in $\{0,1\}$ endowed with the discrete topology.

Comment: Wait, that's very different from the definition i know...i thought I need $f: X \to \{0\}$ and $g:\{0\} \to X$ both continuous s.t. there exists homotopies $h: fg \sim id_{\{0\}}$ and $k:gf \sim id_{X}$ for $X$ o be contractible. How does this equate to "$X$ is contractible if the identity $id_X$ is homotopic to a constant map?" neither $gf, fg$ are guaranteed to be constant in my definition and... Furthermore, Why are considering a homotopy from $X$ to itself? Not $X \to \{0\}$??

Comment: @JohnTrail That's pretty obviously equivalent to your definition: $fg$ can only be *equal* to the identity of $\{0\}$ (as the set consists of only one point), and $gf$ is a constant map, as it factors through a singleton, so that the second condition is the only one not trivial and says exactly that the identity map of $X$ is nullhomotopic... If I was you, I would start by learning and really understanding the definitions you have before attacking the exercises.

Comment: I'm sorry but as a someone who isn't entirely used to the absractness.. I don't find it obvious...i'll sit down and torture my brain for a while alone and if I still don't get it i'll come back stating what exactly troubles me.

Comment: @JohnTrail That's the spirit! Good luck with your study.

Comment: Think I understand that non-path conectedness means non -contractible. However, the line in my Q "*AS* $I$ is path connected ..." bit still confuses me. Rewritten, it seems to say "$I$ is path connected $\Rightarrow$ no path $\omega: I \to X$ s.t. $\omega(0)=0,\omega(1)=1$  $\Rightarrow$ $X$ is not path connected".  How does the first implication work? Why does $I$ **being** path connected allow us to say **no path $\omega$ exists in $X$**? That bit in logic troubles me still

Comment: If non-path connectedness immediately tells me it is non contractible, isn't the proof complete with "$X$ has the discrete topology and thus non path connected thus not contractible. Period"....? Why do I have to fiddle with $I$ at all?

Comment: @JohnTrail Yeah, the part about $I$ being path connected etc. in your reasoning doesn't make much sense imo... Maybe what you want to say is something like "$I$ is path connected $\Rightarrow$  as $\{0,1\}$ is not path connected (in fact, not even connected), there is no surjective continuous map $I\to \{0,1\}$."